# Load Another ViewController In A Button From Main ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

before asking this question, I did some research of course. One of the links or topics I have found on google and on stackoverflow is this:

[How do I load another view controller from the current view controller's implementation file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464025/how-do-i-load-another-view-controller-from-the-current-view-controllers-impleme)

In my case, I have two viewcontrollers in my project, namely:

1. ViewController (ViewController.h and ViewController.m) - my main vc
2. LeftViewController (LeftViewController.h and LeftViewController.m) - my second vc. It will be loaded upon clicking a button from my main vc.

Please take note that it is my 3rd day in my job, self training, and I find objective-c quite hard compared to others, like C# ... Oh I miss C#.

Going on, I tried following the steps from the links that I've got as well as the link I gave at the top.

Here are my codes:

a. Inside my ViewDidLoad in my ViewController.m

```
// add navigation button left
UIButton *leftNavigationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[leftNavigationButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 65, 30, 20)];
[leftNavigationButton setTitle:@"<" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftNavigationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigateLeft) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[leftNavigationButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[leftNavigationButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[leftNavigationButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:leftNavigationButton];
```

b. the method inside my ViewController.m (of course outside the ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)navigateLeft
{
//    LeftViewController *leftViewController = [[LeftViewController alloc] init];
//    [leftViewController viewDidLoad];
    _leftViewController = [[LeftViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UI For LeftButton" bundle:nil];
    [self.ViewController: self.leftViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; //Error in this line, spefically in self.ViewController<---

}
```

c. ViewController.h

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Navigation_Task
//
//  Created by Glenn on 9/4/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Ayi. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// for LeftViewController
@class LeftViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *resultText;

// for LeftViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic)LeftViewController *leftViewController;

@end
```

and lastly, (this is not included in the link above), my code for loading the LeftViewController.

a. viewDidLoad in LeftViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    LeftViewController *leftViewController = [[LeftViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    // set background and title of the view
    [leftViewController.view setBackgroundColor:RGB(19,181,234)];
    leftViewController.title = @"Left View Controller";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:leftViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Sorry if this question is too long, I can't shoot my questions to the developers here in the office, because I'm shy and they don't wanna be bothered :(

Comment: I think the code in your viewDidLoad in LeftViewController.m should be inside the `navigateLeft` method. With that change that code would be correct supposing your first ViewController is inside a NavigationController otherwise you would need a "modal segue" instead. I recommend reading about how navigation controllers works, push segues and modal segues so you can undestand better what you are doing here.

Comment: " think the code in your viewDidLoad in LeftViewController.m should be inside the navigateLeft method" <--- EXACTLY! Before I saw your comment, I did the same thing. And it works! Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 1):

You are using right Controller for navigation i.e. UINavigationController, but to make it navigate I will recommend you to use storyboards. Take your UINavigationController as a rootviewcontroller and further take any UIViewController as its rootviewcontroller and then on 2nd UIViewController to navigate attach a Segue to it and provide it a identifier let say "PushToSecond" and in your buttons Method do the following:

- (void)navigateLeft
  {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushToSecond" sender:self];

}

hope this would help

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I appreciate your reply to me. However, I am not allowed to use Storyboards. I need to hardcode my UI. It's okay now. I have made a big progress to my task, and I have solved my question here. I will answer now my own question. I just wanna ask Abhishek where did you learn or where can I learn those basic terms like rootviewcontroller, and stuffs? Thank you!

Comment: The tutorials offered by RayWenderlich and AppCoda are good one to make you familier with all such terms.

Comment: @user5295097 This is a class from standford university published at itunes u about objective-c coding for ios, its a little old but all the basics are still the same and I think is pretty good way to start. https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774?mt=10

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look into Apple's documentation on UINavigation.

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)

You can either add as many viewController objects into the navigation stack as needed or `present` it incase you need to show it temporarily.

Comment: Ok Kaey. Thanks for your input. I will read that documentation later after office hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my own question.

I have two buttons in my main ViewController.
1 button for LeftViewController
1 button for RightViewController.

Meaning I need to display each new viewcontroller or screen when I click 1 of those buttons.

Here are my codes:

Just inside the event handler (is my term correct? I'm from windows) of the two buttons, put the following:

1. Code for 'Left Screen/View Controller'

   ```
   - (void)navigateLeft
   {
       //    LeftViewController *leftViewController = [[LeftViewController alloc] init];
       //    [leftViewController viewDidLoad];
       //    _leftViewController = [[LeftViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UI For LeftButton" bundle:nil];

           LeftViewController *leftViewController = [[LeftViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

           // set background and title of the view
           [leftViewController.view setBackgroundColor:RGB(19,181,234)];
           leftViewController.title = @"Left View Controller";

           [self.navigationController pushViewController:leftViewController animated:YES];}
   ```
2. Similarly, I need to put the same type of codes (just renaming the leftViewController into RightViewController)

   ```
   - (void)navigateRight
   {
       RightViewController *rightViewController = [[RightViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

       // set background and title of the view
       [rightViewController.view setBackgroundColor:RGB(19,181,234)];
       rightViewController.title = @"Right View Controller";

       [self.navigationController pushViewController:rightViewController animated:YES];
   }
   ```

Now I can push any of the two button and will display a new ViewController (or screen).